# Errors when trying to use openslide and py_wsi

Tags: python, dll, pip

I'm trying to write a Python program to look at and hopefully edit svs files (add tags). I have pip installed openslide-python and py_wsi onto my computer, as well as installed OpenSlide and got a file to open using Visual Studio and C#.

I am getting a failure when I try to import either in PyCharm regarding not being able to locate a dll file. Is there a environmental variable I need to be mapping or something else I need to change?
Here is the error:
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libopenslide-0.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Comment: Answering my own question just in case somebody has the same issue. Python is failing to find the libopenslid-0.dll. You need to go into lowlevel.py and tell it where your openslide dll's exist (should be downloaded separate, these are the C# files). For me it was line 41 in lowlevel.py, replace the code with the exact file destination on your computer.